Depth First Search Time Complexity
Below is Python code for a depth search algorithm.
def add_edge(adj, s, t):
    # Add edge from vertex s to t
    adj[s].append(t)
    # Due to undirected Graph
    adj[t].append(s)
    print('adj add edge', adj)


def dfs_rec(adj, visited, s, loop_count):
    # Mark the current vertex as visited
    visited[s] = True
    print(f'Visited vertex: {s}')

    # Recursively visit all adjacent vertices
    for i in adj[s]:
        loop_count[0] += 1  # Increment the loop counter
        if not visited[i]:
            dfs_rec(adj, visited, i, loop_count)


def dfs(adj, s):
    visited = [False] * len(adj)
    print('Initial visited list:', visited)

    # Create a list to hold loop count as a mutable object
    loop_count = [0]  # This will hold the number of times the loop runs

    # Start DFS recursion
    dfs_rec(adj, visited, s, loop_count)

    # Return the loop count
    return loop_count[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    V = 5

    # Create an adjacency list for the graph
    adj = [[] for _ in range(V)]

    # Define the edges of the graph
    edges = [[1, 2], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 4], [0, 3], [0, 4]]

    # Populate the adjacency list with edges
    for e in edges:
        print('Adding edge:', e)
        add_edge(adj, e[0], e[1])

    source = 1
    print(f"\nDFS traversal from source vertex: {source}")
    total_loops = dfs(adj, source)
    print(f"Total number of times the for loop ran: {total_loops}")

The time complexity is given to be O(V+E). But if I run this code I get this output:

Total number of times the for loop ran: 20

That is O(edges=5)² then how is the time complexity O(V+E)? Shouldn't it be O(V + E²)?
By trying and actually executing the code, it shows the time complexity to be O(V + E²)... I tried running and finding the time complexity? What is my mistake?

Time complexity is not an exact count of operations performed. It is a measure of growth speed. Counting the number of operations for one specific run is generally meaningless.

You wrote:

If I run this code I get this output:

Total number of times the for loop ran: 20

That is O(edges=5)² then how is the time complexity O(V+E)? Shouldn't it be O(V + E²)?

It is not clear how you conclude that it is O(edges=5)², as there are 10 edges, not 5. And 20 is not 5².
The code actually visits each edge in both directions, so for a graph with 10 edges, the for loop will make 20 iterations. Note how your add_edge code doubles the number of directed edges so to make the graph undirected, and every list member of the lists in adj corresponds to one iteration of the loop. If you would have a graph with 1000 edges, there would be 2000 iterations.
And O(2E) is the same as O(E) (See Wikipedia - Big O notation - Multiplication by a constant), and so the overall time complexity is as was expected: O(V+E)
In general, be aware that you cannot derive the time complexity of a program by running it. It is by analysing the code and providing a proof of its complexity.
